# Send to my view a class that contains 2 object lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My goal is: Send to my view a class that contains 2 object lists

For that, here's how I try to proceed:

1. I make a call to the DB which returns to me the list of all my events.
2. I make a second call to the db which returns to me the list of all my sub-events.
3. I have an EventViewModel class that contains a List <_EventsLines> class and a List <_SubEventsLines> class.
4. I need to send the result of these 2 query in a single view but i dont know how could i do that (if it is possible)

I connect to a DB Filemaker and it is based on a single view, that's why I have to make 2 calls.

But then I would like to put the results of these 2 calls in the same object (oEventViewModel) in order to send them back to my view.

Would you have a solution?

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.EventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    Models.EventViewModel oEventViewModel = new Models.EventViewModel
    {
        _EventsLines = (from o in results select o).ToList()
    };

    var xtoFind = new Models.SubEventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var xresults = await client.FindAsync(xtoFind);

    Models.EventViewModel oSubEventViewModel = new Models.EventViewModel
    {
        _SubEventsLines = (from x in xresults select x).ToList()
    };


    ViewBag.Zkf_CTC = 1053;
    ViewBag.JsonList = oEventViewModel;

    return View(oEventViewModel);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public List<EventsLines> _EventsLines { get; set; }
    public List<SubEventsLines> _SubEventsLines { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to use multiple models with a single view. Here I will explain ways one by one.

**1. Using Dynamic Model**
ExpandoObject (the System.Dynamic namespace) is a class that was added to the .Net Framework 4.0 that allows us to dynamically add and remove properties onto an object at runtime. We can pass this dynamically created object to the view and render list of the teacher and student.

**2. Using View Model**
ViewModel is nothing but a single class that may have multiple models. It contains multiple models as a property. It should not contain any method.

**3. Using ViewData** 
ViewData is used to transfer data from the controller to the view. ViewData is a dictionary object that may be accessible using a string as the key. Using ViewData, we can pass any object from the controller to the view. The Type Conversion code is required when enumerating in the view.

**4. Using ViewBag**
ViewBag is similar to ViewData and is also used to transfer data from the controller to the view. ViewBag is a dynamic property. ViewBag is just a wrapper around the ViewData.

**5. Using Tuple**
A Tuple object is an immutable, fixed-size and ordered sequence object. It is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of elements. The .NET framework supports tuples up to seven elements.

**6. Using Render Action Method**
A Partial View defines or renders a partial view within a view. We can render some part of a view by calling a controller action method using the Html.RenderAction method. The RenderAction method is very useful when we want to display data in the partial view. The disadvantages of this method is that there are only multiple calls of the controller.

for further details please refer the [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/) mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just had to modify my code like this and now it works:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.EventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    var xtoFind = new Models.SubEventsLines { Zkf_CTC = 1053 };
    var xresults = await client.FindAsync(xtoFind);

    Models.EventViewModel oEventViewModel = new Models.EventViewModel
    {
        _EventsLines = (from o in results select o).ToList(),
        _SubEventsLines = (from x in xresults select x).ToList()
    };

    ViewBag.Zkf_CTC = 1053;
    return View(oEventViewModel);
}
```